# Get touched event to be continuously active

Tags: java, android, touch

I'm trying to make a game i want to be able to press down on my gamePadUI to keep my character walking. Far as I can tell the TouchEvents only get called 1st time I push down on the screen

I have 2 methods called constantly **update()** which keeps track of my game states and in each state has TouchEvents, so in my Running state it will call **updateRunning()** and checks for TouchedEvent  then map the the x and y points to my gamepadUI

The other is Present() which handles the drawing of each states.

so here is my updateRunning() method that tells the character to walk

```
      public void updateRunning(float deltaTime) {
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Input.TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        touchPoint.set(event.x, event.y);
        guiCam.touchToWorld(touchPoint);

        switch(event.type){
            case TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN:
                gamePad(deltaTime);
            case TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED:
                gamePad(deltaTime);
            case TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP:


        }
    }
}
```

I have tried looping the event but my present then will not get called for there the drawing will not get updated.

what can I do to make it keep TOUCH_DOWN going to call my gamepad method.